# How to delete key inside object inside jsonb array in SQL?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following json data in the `foods` column of my table:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Pasta",
    "price": 45.8,
    "comments": {
      "promo": true,
      "special": true
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Risotto",
    "price": 31.4,
  },
  {
    "name": "Pizza",
    "price": 64.9,
    "comments": {
      "promo": true,
      "special": true
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Hamburguer",
    "price": 14.9,
    "comments": {
      "combo": true
    }
  },
]
```

And I would like to delete all the `promo` keys, to look like this.

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Pasta",
    "price": 45.8,
    "comments": {
      "special": true
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Risotto",
    "price": 31.4,
  },
  {
    "name": "Pizza",
    "price": 64.9,
    "comments": {
      "special": true
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Hamburguer",
    "price": 14.9,
    "comments": {
      "combo": true
    }
  },
]
```

This data may not make much sense because it's an example to create to show the case I'm trying to solve, but with much more data, in which I need to delete a key that exists in some objects (not all, as in the example) that are inside of an jsonb array.
How can I best perform? I use PostgreSQL version 12, so preferably with jsonb functions.

Comment: This would be so easy with a properly normalized data model.

Answer (score 0):

even with jsonb operators you'll need to unnest and reaggregate data, this seems to work:

```sql
create table receipts (
 receipt int,
 foods jsonb
);

insert into receipts values
(1, '[
  {
    "name": "Pasta",
    "price": 45.8,
    "comments": {
      "promo": true,
      "special": true
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Risotto",
    "price": 31.4
  },
  {
    "name": "Pizza",
    "price": 64.9,
    "comments": {
      "promo": true,
      "special": true
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Hamburguer",
    "price": 14.9,
    "comments": {
      "combo": true
    }
  }
]');
```

```sql
SELECT receipt, jsonb_agg(jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_set(element, '{"comments","promo"}', 'null')) ORDER BY ordinality) 
 FROM receipts
 JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(foods) WITH ORDINALITY AS el(element, ordinality)
   ON receipt = 1
GROUP BY receipt
```

.. but it will strip all null values (if any)